Запуск синхронной функции асинхронно
Я пытаюсь понять, как можно обычную синхронную функцию запустить как асинхронную. Пока не нашёл информации об этом. Допустим, есть код:
    def generate_images(amount: int = 0) -> list["Image"]:
        # Generating images.
        pass
    
    async def handle_user_request(request: "Request") -> "Response":
        json = await request.json()
        amount_images = json["amount_images"]
        generated_images = generate_images(amount_images)
        return Response("index.html", context={"generated_images": generated_images"})

Пример абстрактный. Я просто его выдумал, однако он должен отражать суть вопроса: "Как запустить функцию generate_images асинхронно?" Если генерация изображений будет достаточно долгая, то она просто может остановить весь поток выполнения.

Конечно никак, генерация чего-либо это абсолютно синхронный процесс

Спасибо. Я это понимаю. Просто я видел, как делают запросы к БД асинхронными. Например sqlalchemy. Там есть функция run_async. ещё библиотека aiobcryp, которая просто запускает синхронные функции из библиотеки bcrypt асинхронно. Мне бы просто хотелось понять, как это работает.

Ожидние ответа от СУБД - абсолютно асинхронная операция. Генерация чего-либо - абсолютно синхронная, нет смысла даже пытаться их сравнивать

Синхронную асинхронно - никак. Можно обернуть в обычный поток или новый процесс: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools

Ну а aiobcrypt банально вызывает функцию из предыдущего комментария (вот и вы для своего генератора тоже её вызывайте)
